# pydev 4.0 search tab error message 'SearchPage_wholeWord'

Tags: pydev

The latest version of pydev cannot create the search tab somehow. It shows the following error. Any solutions? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is really a bug if you use an older version of Eclipse with the latest PyDev (as it was relying on an internal package)... I've just fixed it: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/4379d7a480d3c8849a5ca1c92047a352014df44f

Cheers!

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse 3.8. Thanks for fixing this!